# Only allow request from one host in Laravel

Tags: laravel, nginx

I have a fronted named neofrontend.com and I want restrict my backend to only accept request from neofrontend.com.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if(
        $request->getHost() !== 'neofrontend.com' 
        && 
        $request->getHost() !== '127.0.0.1' 
        )
    {
        return response("El host {$request->getHost()} no es compatible ", 400);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

I tried this middleware but it always return me my backend host, What can I do?

EDIT:
I tried adding this to cors.php

```
'allowed_origins' => ['*.neofrontend.com'],
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: You should use CORs https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#cors

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, check my edit

Comment: may [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66291392/allow-only-requests-from-domain-and-block-other-sources) can help you

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if(
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] !== 'neofrontend.com' 
        && 
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] !== '127.0.0.1' 
        )
    {
        return response("El host {$request->getHost()} no es compatible ", 400);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```