# Only allow access of api through Api gateway and prevent accessing laravel api routes directly

Tags: laravel, api, api-gateway, kong

I have a laravel api app where we can access the api via `http://mydomain/api/v1/categories`. I have also implemented `kong api gateway` to access those api. How to restrict the accessing of api through laravel api routes and allow only through kong api gateway.

For eg. Accessing `http://mydomain/api/v1/categories` which is laravel route should return `404` but `http://kongdomain/service1/v1/categories should return the response.

This will prevent access of API endpoint which i cannot track and everything passes through Kong API gateway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [allow only requests from domain and block other sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66291392/allow-only-requests-from-domain-and-block-other-sources)

Answer (score 0):

Add required parameter **accessKey=examplekey** in your api request, And then you can access your laravel api with this **examplekey**.